# Sleeping in SendKeys.Send method

Tags: c#, .net

I want to know if there's something similar to `SendKeys.Send("test text {sleep 250} another test text");` in C#.

I know I can use `Thread.Sleep` but I get the string from the user input, and I won't be able to know how many times I have to sleep.

Comment: How do you decide when to sleep and when to send?

Comment: well, there's a textbox, where the user inputs a string to be sent. I've got requests from users to implement a way to make it sleep at certain parts of the string, so if you can put it in a method, and use loops, I would really be grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe there is a way to have `SendKeys.Send()` pause mid string.

If your reading the string to send from user input, you'd be better off parsing this string into a list of partial strings to send and pause between.

i.e. using your example, you'd have a list of strings: `"text text "`,`" another test test"`
and a list of sleep intervals:`250`

The list of sleep intervals would naturally always be 1 item shorter than the list of string to send.

Comment: I would do that, but would make it like {sleep interval} and parse the value using regular expressions! That would make it user-friendly!